# PHP cURL returns FALSE on HTTPS

Tags: php, post, curl

I'm trying to make a bot for: https://coinroll.it/api

**From the site:**
*The Coinroll API is a stateless interface which works over HTTPS. Requests are made using POST variables (application/x-www-form-urlencoded) while responses are encoded in JSON (application/json). A HTTPS connection is required for accessing the API.*

**I have the following code:**

```
$ch = curl_init();
$data = array('user' => 'xxx', 'password' => 'yyy');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://coinroll.it');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
```

When I run this code, it returns a blank page, what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**
I don't actually need to use cURl, if there is a better solution, please tell me.

Comment: Try removing the the `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`. By passing an array for the post fields, cURL will set the correct content-type automatically.

Comment: That doesn't work either.

Comment: Try setting `curl_setopt($ch, 'CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER', false);`. This tells cURL not to try to verify the SSL certificate. Failing that, see  what the output of `echo curl_error($ch);` is.

Comment: It prints `Cannot POST /`

Comment: Without `curl_setopt($ch, 'CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER', false);`, `echo curl_error($ch);` prints `SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed`.

Comment: So with verifypeer = false, it prints `Cannot POST /`?

Comment: It looks like you need to specify an action in the url, for example `https://coinroll.it/api/getbalance` or maybe it's `https://coinroll.it/getbalance`

Comment: Added as an answer incase anyone else hits this question with the same problem :)

Comment: Did two of these up for a friend a few days ago if you want them, one javascript one, another ruby one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can prevent cURL from trying to verify the SSL certificate by using `CURLOPT_VERIFYPEER`.

Also set the action in the URL:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$data = array('user' => 'xxx', 'password' => 'yyy');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://coinroll.it/getbalance');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following cURL option in order to see what happens with the HTTP connection:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
```

When TRUE it outputs verbose information.

Answer (score 0):

Today I had the case where "It had been working fine until now.", but it stopped working when the FQDN changed, and I had to self-sign another certificate, with a different DN.

After a few experiments, it turned out to be that the `Subject Alternate Name` (aka SAN) was not matching the certificate name, and the curl call had not been set with `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2`.

Conclusion: by default, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST is set to 2, but, if your cert SAN is wrong, it will fail, unless you deactivate CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, and, with it, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER.

It is obviously the best practice to set both, and have a SAN that matches the subject.

Reminder: this is how to quickly check the SAN using OpenSSH on command line:

> `openssl x509 -in /etc/ssl/certs/recette.pharmags.fr.crt -noout -text | grep -A1 "Subject Alternative Name"`